# How to use array of object as series data to create multiple series time line chart using Highchart Library

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

getting  data from database through Ajax call. Data is in this format.From

```
[ 
{orderdate:'2014-06-02',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'0.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-05',empname:'Admin',NetSales:'2459072.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-05',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'10368.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-06',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'229864.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-07',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'246427.5000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-09',empname:'Kashif',NetSales:'11200.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-09',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'355915.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-10',empname:'Kashif',NetSales:'22000.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-10',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'685350.0000'}, 
{orderdate:'2014-06-11',empname:'Bilal',NetSales:'848331.0000'}  
]
```

i want a time line Chart using Highchart Library. Orderdate on Xaxis and netSales on y-axis. one plot series for each employee. Like spline irregular time chart on JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/

Comment: Convert it to several 2d-array, like Highcharts expects.

Comment: I think that should be an answer ;)